# Merge two NTFS partitions

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, ntfs, merge

I need to merge 2 partitions:

- Partition 1: Win7 installed, boot partition, NTFS
- Partition 2: Empty, just created from allocated space, NTFS

I've tried Windows disk manager and also various other software but they don't allow me to do it. I want to keep *Partition 1* and expand its space with *Partition 2*

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If ***partition 2 is empty*** and is ***right next to partition 1*** then just delete it and resize partition 1 to fill the newly empty space. **Any tools** that can resize partitions without losing data like [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/), [AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html), [EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/convert-gpt-disk-to-mbr-disk.html), [Macrorit Partition Expert](https://macrorit.com/partition-magic-manager/free-edition.html) or [gparted](https://gparted.org/) can do that. Even Windows disk manager can does the same thing, although with less flexibility (probably because it tries to avoid moving data as much as possible to prevent data loss)

If the partitions are separated from each other then it's a lot trickier. There are 2 solutions

- Convert the disk to [dynamic disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks) which Windows' [logical volume manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) and is the analog of [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) on Linux. Then partition 1 can be extended to any other empty dynamic volumes
- Delete partition 2 then move all partitions between partition 2 and partition 1 to fill the unallocated space, and resize parition 1. This takes much more time and is more risky

Converting to dynamic disk is less risky than the second solution due to the much smaller amount of changes to the file system, but as with any disk modification there are still some risks. It's also more difficult to convert back from dynamic to basic without data loss which often requires professional/proprietary tools. Besides it's incompatible with other OSes (which only matters if you intend to dual boot Linux). Consider those points before proceeding

At this point you should use "volume" for the C:, D:... drives instead of "partition" to avoid confusion, because a volume on basic disks can only consist of a single partition, whereas a volume on dynamic disks can be composed from multiple partitions

> Another difference between basic and dynamic disks is that **dynamic disk volumes can be composed of a set of noncontiguous extents on one or multiple physical disks**. By contrast, a volume on a basic disk consists of one set of contiguous extents on a single disk. Because of the location and size of the disk space needed by the LDM database, Windows cannot convert a basic disk to a dynamic disk unless there is at least 1 MB of unused space on the disk.
>
> [Basic and Dynamic Disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks)

A 1 MB space is needed for the metadata at the end of the disk, so if the disk is MBR you may need to shrink the last partition by 1 MB. After converting just right click on partition 1 and select extend and choose partition 2 to extend into. If the sizes of the 2 partitions are the same you can even use RAID-0 or RAID-1 for speed or safety. Dynamic disk also supports RAID-5 if you have 3 or more partitions.

I've never used dynamic disk on GPT drives so I can't tell, but I think Disk Management will automatically resize the partitions to create space for metadata. Modern versions of Windows leave a small space for the boot partition or the "Microsoft Reserved Partition" for such purposes so generally there shouldn't be any problem. Anyway you should still be cautious, although in any case Disk Management will show you the issues (if any) during conversion

Comment: They are separated from each other. I've started to do the first solution you mentioned. Is it okay to convert for dynamic disk the partition from which the current OS is booted ? Do not really want to get stuck without OS

Comment: MS say "*Dynamic disks have been deprecated from Windows and we don't recommend using them anymore.*" [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk)

Comment: @lx07 the OP is using Windows 7 and [dynamic disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) is the only solution in that case. [Storage Spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces) are only supported [since Windows 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_8#Storage)

Comment: @JZK dynamic disk is a **disk format**, not partition format so you can't have a dynamic partition. You convert the whole hard drive to dynamic and then every volume becomes dynamic (because now volume is just a higher abstraction of partitions [which means it's a bit slower] and is contained in any partitions on the system). Please see my edit

Comment: ok, I'm afraid to do that. Still thank you for the huge answer!!! I will use 2 partitions and one day I reinstall win and start from scratch